# AWS IoT message not arrived with multiple topics subscribed

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

When AWSIotMqttManager is connected, i subscribe to shadow topics

```
mMqttManager.subscribeToTopic("$aws/things/4/shadow/update/delta", AWSIotMqttQos.QOS1, new AWSIotMqttNewMessageCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMessageArrived(String topic, byte[] data) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "onMessageArrived: " + topic);
        }
});

mMqttManager.subscribeToTopic("$aws/things/4/shadow/get/accepted", AWSIotMqttQos.QOS1, new AWSIotMqttNewMessageCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMessageArrived(String topic, byte[] data) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "onMessageArrived: " + topic);
        }
});
```

and then publish an empty message, as [stated in docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/thing-shadow-mqtt.html#get-pub-sub-topic)

```
mMqttManager.publishString("", "$aws/things/4/shadow/get", AWSIotMqttQos.QOS1);
```

I get no callback.

When i remove subscription to delta, i got it.

Why? How to to subscribe on two topics on app start?